# Is it thread-safe to read an instance variable while calling a setter from another thread?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety

I have an object with a property:

```
@interface Car
@property(strong) NSLicensePlate *licensePlate;
@end
```

I use the property in a method:

```
- (void) doSomething {
    [_licensePlate frobnicate];
}
```

And the property value can be changed in another method:

```
- (void) doSomethingElse {
    [self setLicensePlate:[_licensePlateDealer cleanLicensePlate]];
}
```

Now, if the `-doSomethingElse` method is called from another thread while I access the license plate property using the instance variable (as seen in the `-doSomething` method), is it possible to get a segfault?

Is it possible that the `-setLicensePlate` setter releases the value stored in `_licensePlate` right before I call `-frobnicate` on it and before a new valid value is assigned? And would it help to call `[self licensePlate]` instead of using `_licensePlate` directly?

Comment: @bbum - I understand why you marked this as a dupe, but it's not quite (or not to that question, at least) because (a) he's not asking what atomicity is, but rather whether you can enjoy it if you use the ivar; and (b) he's asking about the lifecycle of an object that might be running a method when the property is set to another object on another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enjoy the `atomic` behavior (which is the default behavior that you get because you didn't specify the `nonatomic` qualifier) of this property, you must use the getter (`self.licensePlate` or `[self licensePlate]`), not use the ivar (`_licensePlate`).

In general, it's usually prudent to use the getters and setters everywhere except (a) the `init` method; and (b) and custom accessor methods. The overhead is negligible and you avoid spectrum of potential problems ranging from atomicity, memory semantics, KVO, future-proofing code in case you customize accessor methods at some future date, etc.

But, assuming you access your property only through the accessor methods (the getters and setters), the `atomic` qualifier, as described by [*Programming with Objective-C: Encapsulating Data*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW37) ensures that the pointer, itself, that you are retrieving/setting is will not be corrupted by another thread:

> [Atomic] means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value is always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from different threads.

In answer to your question, if the other thread changes the `licensePlate` property, while the `frobnicate` method is running on the other thread, that original object will not be released until that method returns.

But to be clear, the `atomic` qualifier does *not* ensure thread safety. As the above guide goes on to warn us:

> **Note:** Property atomicity is not synonymous with an object’s thread safety.
>
> Consider an `XYZPerson` object in which both a person’s first and last names are changed using atomic accessors from one thread. If another thread accesses both names at the same time, the atomic getter methods will return complete strings (without crashing), but there’s no guarantee that those values will be the right names relative to each other. If the first name is accessed before the change, but the last name is accessed after the change, you’ll end up with an inconsistent, mismatched pair of names.
>
> This example is quite simple, but the problem of thread safety becomes much more complex when considered across a network of related objects. Thread safety is covered in more detail in [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).

So, it *might* be thread-safe to use `frobnicate` on one thread while doing other stuff on another thread, but it also might not. It depends upon all the different things that can be done with this license plate object. Because the protections offered by `atomic` are so minimalist, we frequently will employ some synchronization (via GCD serial queue or GCD reader-writer pattern, or via any of the synchronization methods outlined in the [*Threading Programming Guide: Synchronization*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) such as locks) to coordinate interaction from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

When you define properties, you can set them as `atomic` (the default) or `nonatomic`.

Since you're using the `atomic` default, you should be fine about thread safety, but that also depends on how you implemented `frobnicate`, `setLicensePlate:` and `cleanLicensePlate`.

Please refer to this question to get more details about `atomic` vs `nonatomic`: [What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/whats-the-difference-between-the-atomic-and-nonatomic-attributes/)